# Forum style discussion between new users

Tags: discussion, new-users, forums

While reviewing the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601486/jquery-button-click-not-firing) and getting some answers using the comments area, I noticed that quite many new users all answered the question, based on the original assumption, or just answered to get more information from the starting post (forum style communication)

Now I cannot really do something else than just point them out they were wrong and maybe send some downvotes for downright wrong answers (and question).

Eventually an answer got accepted that gives an idea what might be wrong, but it's not the most complete answer. I think the user just got chased away because of the downvotes and choose to accept an answer and get it over with.

This post is now quite messed up (due to the many edits in the starting posts) and the different analyses the original post starter took.

I now voted to close the topic (as off-topic), but how should one approach such a scenario?

Comment: [*This always works for me. Try your luck here.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35602125/4151918)

Comment: @CodeCaster Sounds like a good tip, I only downvoted the downright lucky guesses but in the end it's not my responsibility to make sure everything is as the SO Guidelines intend it. Is there no way that more priviliged admins can clean up such questions? (I'm sure you have quite some admin powers there ;))

Comment: To be clear, it is not your *responsibility*, but it is well within your powers to do something about it when you see something go(ing) wrong.

Comment: @CodyGray I agree, which is also why I arrived here to ask the question and to point it out that this question doesn't fit. I also voted to close and tried to clear things up in the original question as well, much more I couldn't do, which is why I ment, this is no longer my responsibility :)

Comment: Creating good Q+A that is useful to programmers for years to come and not just another notch on the 20-million-question bedpost is hard work.  Not everybody is willing to put in the labor to get there, usually least of all the questioner.  Or for that matter a new user that is chasing the rep number, an activity that's strongly encouraged by the site owners.  We can no longer get rid of the chaff, there simply are not enough users around to keep up by a factor of ~two.  Hard to fix of course.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Why are people so afraid of revenge-votes?  I've never had one, and I do leave comments explaining my downvotes.  I do try to be helpful in the comment if possible, since I've already spent the time reading what I'm commenting on to be sure it deserves the downvote.  Is revenge-voting only a thing in more popular tags?  I usually hang out in the asm / x86 tags, since that's a rarer area of expertise where I feel like if I don't post good answers, it might not happen at all for some worthwhile questions.  I don't think one or two downvotes would stop me anyway.

Comment: @Peter it is very common in the C# tag, at least. I'm not afraid of them, I have some reputation points to spare, but it just sucks that quite some users cannot take constructive criticism. They see any criticism on their crappy code as a direct attack on themselves, and refuse to learn anything from any information thrown at them. Well, it's their loss.

Comment: _"... because posting an answer requires the least effort and has the highest (reputation) yields."_ - You say it like taking the least effort is a bad thing. An answer that _may_ solve the problem has 2 outcomes: 1) It solves the problem and the OP leaves feedback letting me know 2) It doesn't solve the problem and the OP leaves feedback letting me know. If I leave a comment asking for further clarification it only gives outcome 2 meaning I will definitely need to come back, taking me away from helping the next person. Note once the issue is resolved I'll tidy my answer to be specific.

Comment: @Ryan I think we've had this discussion before somewhere, but we're not here to just help the OP. We should not attempt to answer every question; we should strive to either make every question clear or get it closed.

Comment: Indeed I think we did and I find myself voting to close a lot more often as a result, I just can't always fight the urge to help OP!

Comment: @RyanfaeScotland Showing the bad example (asking furter clarifications inside an answer) doesn't really help new users, and neither does it help the OP. If I browse the main page, I will only rarely go into posts that already have one or two answers (maybe the wrong attitude, I won't contest that :)). If those answers are such a question answer that might be deleted, and don't help the OP who asked the question, then it might divert other people from getting answers to their question aswell. With your logic, you also still have to go back ;)

Comment: @HansPassant I also think it works good as it is, however I am only inquiring if I could do more to prevent such a behavior from become standard (as CodeCaster points out, it feels like an epidemic) and if I exhausted all my possibilities.

Comment: *...They see any criticism on their crappy code as a direct attack on themselves, and refuse to learn anything from any information thrown at them. Well, it's their loss...* @CodeCaster well if you tell them like that, I guess they could take it personal :D I got the beer, gin and chips already in the mean time :D

Comment: @Icepickle Good god, just viewed the question you gave as an example and I don't mean asking for feedback like _that_! I mean giving the answer 'It sounds like the problem is caused by X, try doing Y to solve it. If that doesn't work it could also be Z but if it is neither of these please add some clarity to your question regarding Q.' Yes, you always have to come back but if your answer is right you can come back in your own time and tidy up. If you only comment and the clarity is given you need to answer then and there or someone else will swoop in and scoop the answer you done the work for.

Comment: @Icepickle no, I tend to be somewhat more constructive than _"your code is crap"_, don't worry. I am a fan of brevity though.